# Adding Left-Padding to PowerShell Out-String

Tags: powershell, output

I'm trying to making a small library of PowerShell functions to make things easier for myself and my team. For example:

```
$toReturn=Get-ADUser $name -Properties msRTCSIP-UserEnabled| Select msRTCSIP-UserEnabled | Format-List | Out-String
```

Where the output is like:

```
msRTCSIP-UserEnabled : True
```

Now, all I want to do is add a few empty spaces before the output (msRTCSIP-UserEnabled).

Basically, I want to add a certain amount of spaces to any Out-String.

Note: I'm not pulling just one value, its more like a bunch of them, so the output looks more like:

```
msRTCSIP-UserEnabled           : True
msRTCSIP-DeploymentLocator     : SRV:
msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress    : SIP:XXXX@XX.com
userPrincipalName              : XXXX@XX.com
msRTCSIP-InternetAccessEnabled : True
msRTCSIP-FederationEnabled     : True
```

[Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSZX3.jpg)
I'd like to indent the whole output a little more to the right in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing what you want. For example:

```
$data = @(
    "msRTCSIP-UserEnabled           : True",
    "msRTCSIP-DeploymentLocator     : SRV:",
    "msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress    : SIP:XXXX@XX.com",
    "userPrincipalName              : XXXX@XX.com",
    "msRTCSIP-InternetAccessEnabled : True",
    "msRTCSIP-FederationEnabled     : True"
)

$data | %{ "`t" + $_ } | Out-String

$data | %{ "    {0}" -f $_} | Out-String

$data | %{ [string]::Format("    {0}", $_) }
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you for the update, just one more thing, how do I get the output I get from powershell into a comma separated String array?